# Google Analytics - Track URL Change?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I hope someone can help, I can't seem to find the answer to my question...

I have a Wordpress website which uses WP Job Manager to allow people to apply for jobs.

I'm trying to set up google analytics so we can see the amount of people applying for jobs.

The trouble I'm having is, when you apply for a job, a form pops out in a modal box and when it's submitted, there is no thank you page, just a thank you box which appears on the page.

This thank you box seems to have a class of: .job-manager-message.

The other thing it does is add this to the end of the URL: /?application_success=1 - Which I assume triggers the thank you message. This seems to be the only unique things that happens when you click the submit button.

So I cant track the submit button, because that would throw up a 'hit' if someone doesn't fill the form out properly.

I can't track the div: .job-manager-message because that seems to be a generic container for any job manager message.

So that leave the addition to the URL as the only unique thing that happens...

I might be overthinking it all, but can anyone help? :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried GTM form submission trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using google tag manager to deploy your google analytics tag you can use the below code to return the message as a variable then use the variable equals “whatever message appears” added to a pageview trigger to trigger the event.

```
fucntion () {
let message = document.getElementByClassName(“ job-manager-message”).innerText; //if this doesn’t work try .value
return message
}
```